# Убрать перенаправление c http на https в .htaccess

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess

Есть два домена: http://one.ru и http://two.ru. При переходе на них сразу переходим на http**s**://one.ru и http**s**://two.ru.

```
SetEnvIf X-HTTPS 1 HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-HTTPS} !1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Как изменить .htaccess так, чтобы при переходе на http://two.ru перенаправления на HTTPS не было.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользовался этим:

```
RewriteRule http://one.ru/$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```